# Standard format of resignation letter in Germany

Tags: germany, employment, contracts

I've an infinite contract with a company and now I wish to leave that company. Is there any standard format of resignation letter I should sign?

The letter which I got from HR states as below, please let me know if it's fine to sign

> Termination of my employment relationship
>
> Dear sir, Madam
>
> I hereby give notice that I wish to terminate the existing employment contract from date xxxx. My last day of employment will be xxx.
>
> Please confirm this termination letter.
>
> Sincerely
> ...

Comment: You might want to post this on workplace. stackexchange if nobody replies here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That template looks perfectly fine. The only requirement in Germany is that it has to be in writing and it has to identify you and the contract.

Assuming you sign it with your name, it’s good.

Comment: Does it necessarely need to be signed back from employee too?

Comment: @jasenkoh Do you mean Employ*er*? Then **no**, in theory it's valid once you signed it and the Employer has received it. *However*, proving that the employer received it when you hand it in in person is difficult and the easiest way to get it legally valid proof is to have a written and signed confirmation from your employer. Bigger companies have a procedure for this where they just fill out their companies form for this process and print it out for you and sign it.

Comment: ok thanks, I gave resignation letter to my HR but didn't get any signed confirmation from them so I was wondering if it's needed by law

Comment: Well, if they are nice, you don't need it. If they are Evil Corp and just shrug and flat out lie and say "don't know what that guy is talking about, we never got anything like that" then you'd need it.

Comment: heh let's hope that's not the case :)